# Pandas: how to sequentially alternate between calculating difference between two rows and skip calculation for the next row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, difference

The idea would be to calculate the difference between the first and second rows, and store that value in the second row (similar to `.diff()`).

Then, skip the calculation between the second and third rows, and place `0`.

Then, repeat this procedure throughout all rows in the Dataframe.

For example:

```
     A
0    100
1    101
2    103
3    107
4    110
5    120
6    150    
7    170
```

`df['B'] = df['A'].diff()`

```
     A       B
0    100     Nan
1    101     1
2    103     2
3    107     4
4    110     3
5    120     10
6    150     30
7    170     20
```

What I would like to achieve is:

```
     A       B
0    100     0
1    101     1
2    103     0
3    107     4
4    110     0
5    120     10
6    150     0
7    170     20
```

Any suggestions on how to accomplish this using Pandas (or Python)?

Comment: unfortunately index may not begin at `0`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just `mask` the result

```
df['B'] = df['A'].diff().mask(df.index%2!=1,0)
df
Out[469]: 
     A     B
0  100   0.0
1  101   1.0
2  103   0.0
3  107   4.0
4  110   0.0
5  120  10.0
6  150   0.0
7  170  20.0
```

Or we do `groupby`

```
df['B'] = df.groupby(df.index//2).A.diff().fillna(0)
Out[472]: 
0     0.0
1     1.0
2     0.0
3     4.0
4     0.0
5    10.0
6     0.0
7    20.0
Name: A, dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks @BENY - will this work if index begins at non-zero value?

Comment: just checked, yes it does...

Comment: @pepe work with continue index ~